# CSS3 keyframe animation reverse jumping keyframes

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a simple CSS3 keyframe animation that I would like to **reverse while it runs**. 
See the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/breizo/EUVAv/

```
@-webkit-keyframes transform-keyframes {
0%      {-webkit-transform:translateX(0px) translateY(0px) rotate(270deg);}
25%     {-webkit-transform:translateX(200px) translateY(0px) rotate(270deg);}
25.01%  {-webkit-transform:translateX(200px) translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);}
50%     {-webkit-transform:translateX(200px) translateY(200px) rotate(0deg);}
50.01%  {-webkit-transform:translateX(200px) translateY(200px) rotate(90deg);}
75%     {-webkit-transform:translateX(0px) translateY(200px) rotate(90deg);}
75.01%  {-webkit-transform:translateX(0px) translateY(200px) rotate(180deg);}
100%    {-webkit-transform:translateX(0px) translateY(0px) rotate(180deg);}
}
```

Anybody has a trick to **prevent the animation from jumping to another keyframe** than the current one?
It looks like it is jumping to the keyframe symmetrical to 1/2 of the duration.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "prevent the animation from jumping to another keyframe"? Do you mean the animation-jump from 100% to 0% or another issue?

Comment: if you look at the jsFiddle link, when you click on the toggle button, the triangle does not stay in place to revert direction. Instead, it jumps somewhere else before reverting.

Comment: when you reverse the animation, you keep the percentage of the duration, not the keyframe. And since you reverse the timeflow also, you end in another keyframe.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same flavor of jumpiness using CSS to animate a 3D carousel product catalog In two directions based on :hover.

Having fiddled with obvious ideas like animation-fill-mode:forwards and such with not the least good fortunes what finally solved it was to mix in two bits of transition syntax with a tiny duration and the transform itself as the property. In the course of transition chasing to catch transform's state ,it's updates To the element being transformed remained intact , and the effect seems to fit the specs , so it should be a valid solution

```
transition-duration: 0.2s;transition-property:transform;
```

pardon any typos ,as I"m using a pad.

Answer (score 0):

After much hair pulling (not much left...) I ended up using the excellent greensock library: http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/
It gives much more control to the whole animation.